# Using JSON.stringify and can't access the JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using php and using json_encode() function I returned/echoed JSON array. I was using jquery ajax and successfully retrieved this data:

```
[{"id":"1132","city":"Manila Central Post Office","province":"Manila"}]
```

I use this code on my Javascript btw:

```
var val = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
```

and when I tried to accessed the data on the array like:

```
console.info(val.city); // results to undefine
```

It gives me 'undefined' result. I tried doing For in loop still doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, any help would be great. THANKS

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path,
    cache: false,
    data: postData,
    success: function (result) {
        var val = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result, false, replacer));
        var val2 = jQuery.parseJSON(val);
        console.info(val2);
        console.info(val2.id);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#sys_msg").html(e);
        $("#myModal").modal({
            show: true,
            backdrop: false,
            keyboard: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `val` is an array, the object with a `city` key is the first item in that array. Why do you stringify then re-parse it, anyway?

Comment: can you add ajax code in the question above?

Comment: var val = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result, false , replacer));
var val2 = jQuery.parseJSON(val);

Comment: i tried that stringify then parse

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: You don't have to `stringify` it. Once you `stringify` it. It will become `string` and you can't access it like an array.

Comment: @JomarLlevado look at the answer posted. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36259118/1059101

Answer (score 2):

`val` is an array. You need to specify index like below.

```js
var result = [{ "id": "1132", "city": "Manila Central Post Office", "province": "Manila" }];
var val = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
alert(val[0].city);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Object { id="1132",  city="Manila Central Post Office",  province="Manila"}]. It turned back into object again.

Comment: I've up voted since you were able to extract the JSON data. THANKS :)

Comment: In fact you don't need use this `var val = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));` line. You can use `result[0].city` directly. @JomarLlevado

Answer (score 1):

Here `val` is an array of objects, so you cannot access the `city` value directly by calling `val.city`. If the data being returned is already encoded by using `json_encode()`, then you simply need to use `$.parseJSON(data)`. The following code snippet shows how to do this-

```js
var temp = '[{"id":"1132","city": "Manila Central Post Office", "province":"Manila"},{"id":"1133","city": "Another Test Post Office", "province":"Test"}]'; //Defined temp as string since the data response returned from the server should also be a json encoded string.

var val = $.parseJSON(temp);

$.each(val, function(index, item) {
    var city = item.city;
    $('.container').append('City: '+city+'<br/>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: @JomarLlevado What other problem are you facing?

Comment: I'm trying to pull the data, which is what you give to me and I'm trying to put it in a specified html DOM such as input

Comment: In order to put the data in a specified html DOM, you can simply do something like `$('#inputFieldCity').val(city);` where `inputFieldCity` is the ID of your input field.

Answer (score 0):

See, the issue can be easily resolved by `dataType:"json"`. If you don't have this attached in your ajax code then the returned response will be a json string and in this case only you have to parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()`.

So, you can add the `dataType` to the ajax or instead just only parse it.

```
success: function(result){
  var val = jQuery.parseJSON(result); // or JSON.parse(result);
  console.info(val[0].city);
},
```

With `dataType`:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  cache: false,
  data: postData,
  dataType: 'json', //<-----add this here
  success: function(result) {
    for (o in result) { // <----and just use this way
      console.info(o.city);
    }
  },
  error: function(e) {
    $("#sys_msg").html(e);
    $("#myModal").modal({
      show: true,
      backdrop: false,
      keyboard: true
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `stringify` it then parse it to JSON again. You can just add `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path,
    cache: false,
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (result) {

        console.info(result);
        console.info(result.id);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#sys_msg").html(JSON.stringify(e));
        $("#myModal").modal({
            show: true,
            backdrop: false,
            keyboard: true
        });
    }
});
```